# Center button between two other buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to center a button in the middle of other two buttons. I tried using `weight` but with no luck (`Android Studio` keep saying that there's an error), using `layout_marginRight` is not a good idea because it's not resolution independent.
Here's my `XML` code I hope it can help you understanding my problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottom_LeftButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lft"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottom_LeftCenterButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LftC"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottom_CenterButtom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Cnt" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottom_RightCenterButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RhtC"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottom_RightButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rht"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: What about using LinearLayout with weight?

Comment: use `linearLayout` .

Comment: You can't use weights in RelativeLAyouts.

Comment: Remove the relative layout which is inside the linear layout.. Now linear layout should be the direct parent for those buttons and hence use weight. Supply some wieght sum for the linear layout and then use weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottom_LeftButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lft"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottom_LeftCenterButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LftC"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottom_CenterButtom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Cnt" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottom_RightCenterButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RhtC"
           android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottom_RightButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rht"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is working like a charm I didn't know about RelativeLayout and Weight. Every button have now a different size how can I five them all the same size?

Comment: Remove  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" and set weight as 3 in all button@#user3320009

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

To keep all the buttons in of same size you need to to keep the width attribute to "fill_parent". Below is the working xml. weightsum should be equal to the number of buttons you want to use.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: for three buttons keep the weightsum as 3

Comment: `weightSum` is really **useless**. and `fillParent` has been **deprecated** with API Level 8.

Comment: well, u can replace fill_parent with match_parent @FrankN.Stein. This solution keeps the width of the elements same even if the text length increases

Comment: Yes, you should. Also note that the RelativeLayout you have around the LinearLayout is **useless** and also **bad for performances**.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear layout then you include "WEIGHT"to your Button,because weight belongs to linearlayout.